# My css and html code is acting very strange

Tags: html, css

my code is acting super strange, first, i cant get css to work.
randomly in my code there was lines that were grayed out like if it was a comment but there was no comments, i pressed the spacebar after each end of line and it went back to normal, pretty strange.
then whenever i tries to give css properties and classes, it wouldnt give them. i just reopened my computer and last time it worked perfectly fine.
i gave the right link to the css stylesheet in html, ive checked.

here is just one example :

home.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homestyle.css" 
    media="screen" />
</head>

(... more code)

<h1 class="lorem">hello</h1>
```

stylesheet.css

```
body {
     margin: 0px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


(... more code)

.lorem{
    color: white;
    background-color: aqua;
}


(... more code)
```

Comment: Where's the PHP?

Comment: try restarting your computer..

Comment: I've tested your code and found no problem with it. Meaning the problem is on the unsupplied code

Comment: @Forbs i dont have php yet, i just name my file extension as .php for later. right now i am doing the html and css

Comment: @hans-könig Ill try to supply the unlisted code,but first ill try retsrating my computer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="homestyle.css" 
media="screen" />
```

by

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css" media="screen">
```

because the file called `stylesheet.css` and you call `homestyle.css`, Or just rename your css file to `homestyle.css` .

Comment: Yeah, i feel pretty stupid for not trying that haha, it did work for the most part, now ill check if it works 100%